# ffmpeg Format settings, Matrix bt709

Tags: ffmpeg, color-space

Does anyone know how I can achieve the following color space (**bt.709**) via FFmpeg?
Here is what I have now in my files...

[image]

As you can see there is `Format settings, Matrix` as default, how can I set it like this :

- Format settings (Matrix) : Custom or Standard
- Component Color primaries : BT.709
- Transfer characteristics : BT.709
- Matrix coefficients : BT.709

Thank you

Comment: With re-encoding or without?

Comment: I would be glad to know any  solution with recording and without it

Answer (score 15, accepted):

With re-encoding, use

```
ffmpeg -i test.mxf -c copy -c:v mpeg2video -b:v 5000k \
       -color_primaries 1 -color_trc 1 -colorspace 1 out.mxf
```

In Mediainfo, at the end of the video stream attributes, you should see the three color-related entries. Note that **Format settings (Matrix)** is related to MPEG quantization and not color.

Comment: Mulvya, Thank you for your help, Indeed -color_primaries 1 -color_trc 1 -colorspace 1 is working, but I would like also to know how to set Format settings (Matrix) : Custom or Standard if it would be possible, thank you.

Answer (score 11):

After much searching, the secret option that has to be passed to ffmpeg for proper BT.709 encoding is found to be inside the video filter feature.

**Note:** The `-vf` video filter option will actually transform the RGB values while the other 709 flags just indicate what flags will be included in the container settings (*eg:* as some MP4 metadata).

This example starts with a 32x32 png that is set to (RGB = `0, 0, 255`) or max blue.

```
ffmpeg -y -i Blue32x32.png -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset:v slow -profile:v baseline -crf 20 -vf scale=out_color_matrix=bt709 -color_primaries bt709 -color_trc bt709 -colorspace bt709 Blue32x32_709.m4v
ffmpeg -y -i Blue32x32_709.m4v Blue32x32_709.y4m
od -v -t u1 Blue32x32_709.y4m
```

The output of the last/bottom FFmpeg command will dump the byte values as **ints,** you should see (Y Cb Cr) values as `Y = 32, Cb = 240, Cr = 118` which means the BT.709 conversion matrix is being used in the `.m4v` file. When decoded back to RGB the transformed color is `2, 0, 255`.

Comment: "Note that the -vf video filter option actually transforms while the other 709 flags just indicate what flags will be included in the container" 

Indeed -color_primaries 1 -color_trc 1 -colorspace 1 only writes the metadata information. While the filter approach will transform your content to BT.709

Comment: Just FYI, it appears that this ffmpeg command creates only Gamma 1.0 YCbCr data, more info about 709 gamma issues can be found at this SO question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53911662/does-h-264-encoded-video-with-bt-709-matrix-include-any-gamma-adjustment

Comment: Since primaries for sRGB and BT.709 are the same, and AFAIK gamma correction should do nothing to 0000FF, shouldn't we get straight-up RGB-to-YCbCr conversion in this case? I do get Y = 41, Cb = 240, Cr = 110 when following these instructions, and indeed this matches http://www.picturetopeople.org/p2p/image_utilities.p2p/color_converter?color_space=RGB&color_channel1=0&color_channel2=0&color_channel3=255&ResultType=view .  Where did the "Y = 32, Cb = 240, Cr = 118" values come from?