# Difference between TransferFunction and YCbCrMatrixKey for CVImageBuffer?

Tags: objective-c, macos, yuv, color-space, core-video

I have an [CVImageBuffer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corevideo/cvimagebuffer-q40). Reading its attachments with [CMFormatDescriptionGetExtensions](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremedia/1489170-cmformatdescriptiongetextensions?language=objc), I get:

```
CVImageBufferYCbCrMatrix: ITU_R_601_4
CVImageBufferTransferFunction: ITU_R_709_2
```

Now I would like to convert the YCbCr values to RGB.

- What [Color Conversion Standard](http://www.equasys.de/colorconversion.html) should I use, BT.601 or BT.709?
- What's the difference between [CVImageBufferYCbCrMatrix](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corevideo/cvimagebuffer/image_buffer_transfer_function_constants?language=objc) and [kCVImageBufferTransferFunction](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corevideo/cvimagebuffer/image_buffer_transfer_function_constants?language=objc)?

Comment: 601 were developed for SD-TV resolution. BT-709 for HD-content. Use 709.

Comment: Thanks, but this was clear for me. But I don't know what the difference between the Matrix and the TransferFunction is, so I'm not sure in what format the data actually is...

Comment: This SO answer shows how to encode and specify the matrix to use with ffmpeg. I have yet to find a clear answer on the TransferFunction issue. https://stackoverflow.com/a/53806290/763355

Comment: This SO question shows the meaning of tansfer function, it is the gamma curve. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53911662/does-h-264-encoded-video-with-bt-709-matrix-include-any-gamma-adjustment

Comment: "601 were developed for SD-TV resolution. BT-709 for HD-content. Use 709" and you are wrong. This uses BT.601 matrix. Also transfer function (OETF, not EOTF) in BT.2020, BT.709, BT.601 is the same. Only in BT.2100 PQ tranfer was introduced. Let me guess this is JPEG? JPEG uses full range BT.601 matrix.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 things: ColourPrimaries, TransferCharacteristics and MatrixCoefficients per ITU-T H.273. From https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/corevideo.cvimagebufferycbcrmatrix?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12 CVImageBufferYCbCrMatrix Enum is actually what is called MatrixCoefficients by H.273 and CVImageBufferTransferFunction is what is called TransferCharacteristics. Those are two parts of encoding process. So to decode you need to use BT.601 reverse (from 8 bit /10 bit/ 12 bit YCbCr to float values, then from YCbCr float to R' G' B' float values (using 601 matrix)) and those values will already be in BT.709 transfer function and I suppose MacOS can then simply convert it to your sRGB transfer with DCI-D65 primaries or whatever display you are using.